# How do I find usages of my class where it is used as a certain implemented interface?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Consider the following example:

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
...
}
```

How do I find the places where `Foo` is used as a `Comparable`?

Edit: I have opened a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209540

Comment: Did you [try](https://i.imgur.com/29KbRXh.png) the [SSR](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html)?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you but that would only find the class definition, not the usages.

Comment: Please clarify your question supplying a couple of examples what do you want to find and what should not appear in the search results. Do you want to find class references or expressions of type Foo?

Comment: Use "Find Usage" (Alt + F7) on the compareTo method?

Comment: That will not work. It gives me two options: To search for usages of `Foo.compareTo()` or to search for usages of the base method `Comparable.compareTo()`. The former gives me no results, because the method is never used on variables with declared type Foo. The latter gives me all calls to compareTo, on *any* Comparable, which is obviously a crapload and not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching through `command + shift + f` and enter `Comparable<Foo>` as input. it will point out all the instances where it occurred.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not find usages where `Foo` is used as a type parameter, e.g. `bar(new Foo())` for a function `bar(Comparable<T>)`.